# No sound from QCY-T13 Earbuds in Windows 11

Tags: android, windows-11

I am having problem connecting my QCY-T13 Earbuds to Windows 11.

I have paired the QCY-APP that appears in the Add Devices menu, but when it is paired, it does not output audio.

I have successfully paired them to my android phone using the app.

None of the answers to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1310342/connected-bluetooth-headphones-dont-appear-as-playback-device-in-windows-10) helped

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, and thank you for your input. Unfortunately this question will be deleted. SE sites aren't discussion boards. Think of these as remote technical support. I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how these sites work.

Comment: I understand why you created a new "question" instead of answering the linked one. Even in such case the post should be a question and your solution should be posted as an answer (below). Please read [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) Alternatively, if you really want to answer the linked question, I can unprotect it for a while. The other question is tagged `windows-10`, yours is `windows-11` and *maybe* specific to QCY-T13 (I don't know), so *maybe* it's good to have a separate question. One way or another the solution should be posted as an answer.

Comment: I will submit the answer to the question if that's okay? I'll try to be more descriptive of the problem I was having as well

Comment: @grayatrox Do you mean the other question? Do you want me to unprotect it for you?

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski I mean this one. I have just restructured the "Question" I don't have enough rep to answer the other one.

Comment: @grayatrox "I don't have enough rep to answer the other one" – because it's protected. I could unprotect it, I still can. If you still want to keep and answer this question here, then now you should wait until the question is reopened. To increase your chances you may add a statement like "none of the answers to [this other question](https://superuser.com/q/1310342) helped" (if it's true).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think that opening a new question is best. They are a different device and that other question is quite old, but thanks for the suggestion about adding that line.

Comment: OK, I voted to reopen your question and I'm not going to unprotect the other one.

Comment: Hint: your solution is still visible in the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1770920/revisions). When the question gets reopened you may copy from there, there is no need to retype the entire answer.